# Enable Exchange 2013 remote PowerShell user without another enabled user

Tags: powershell, exchange, exchange-2013

I am fighting a Exchange Powershell remote issue. I'm trying to run Exchange troubleshooter and its telling me my user isn't remote PS enabled. It's been enabled in the past, along with other admin accounts, which are getting the same error.

Everything I read says you must be logged in with a remote PS enabled user. How can I enable it for all users (temporary) without an enabled user?

Thanks,
Travis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. A binding got wiped out on IIS. I don't know why it didn't occur to me, but our internal DNS scheme is different than our external. I had to re-add the binding for the internal servername.

Thanks for looking everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge, you must enable it to access remote powershell, there is no temporary method for an without enabled user.

Run below command to enable remote powershell for a specific user:

```
Set-User "user01" -RemotePowerShellEnabled $true
```

In addition, By default, all user accounts have access to remote PowerShell. However, to actually use remote PowerShell to connect to an Exchange server, the user needs to be a member of a management role group, or be directly assigned a management role that enables the user to run Exchange cmdlets.

For more details: [Control remote PowerShell access to Exchange servers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/control-remote-powershell-access-to-exchange-servers?view=exchange-ps)

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks. It's acting like all users have been disabled, but the overall remote PS is enabled. There may be another issue causing this, but everything I need to troubleshoot needs remote powershell so I'm stuck in a loop. All users are in the same management groups now as when they were working.